# I need to make a sprite move horizontally for a predetermined distance, flip horizontally, and return

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm trying to make a penguin sprite slide back and forth along platforms I have made. I have achieved this however I am really struggling to make the sprite flip horizontally once it moves back. I believe I may need to change my method of making the penguins move in order to incorporate the flip. I saw lots of threads about rotating around the Y axis but I don't know how to incorporate it. As it stands the penguins just goes back and forth always facing the positive x direction. The game is in 2D on Unity and is written in C#. Thanks for any advice. :)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Enemy1 : MonoBehaviour {
private SpriteRenderer SpriteRenderer;
public float min = 2f;
public float max = 3f;
public int x = 0;
public bool facingRight = true;

 // Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    min = transform.position.x;
    max = transform.position.x + 27;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 2, max - min) + min, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can track the direction of your sprite and use `localScale.x` or `flipX`:

```
float _prevX = 0f;
...
void Update()
{
    float newX = Mathf.PingPong (Time.time * 2, max - min);
    transform.position = new Vector3(newX + min, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
    scale.x = newX < _prevX ? -1 : 1;
    transform.localScale = scale;
    _prevX = newX;
}
```

Another way: track when your sprite near "edge" points and "flip" only then, otherwise the first way is more general if you rotate your sprite earlier for some reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I've messed with sprites but i think setting transform.scale.z = -1 will flip the sprite so it faces the other direction.